# How to fix scaffolding issues when building a CRUD app with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to make a CRUD app using this tutorial: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/aspnet-core-basics-build-complete-crud-application-vs-code

I cannot get it to do the scaffolding and automatically add the CRUD webpages. Any ideas on how to fix this? What I find online so far has not helped.

When I run this in the terminal:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TodoController 
      -dc ApplicationDbContext -m Todo --useDefaultLayout -sqlite 
      --referenceScriptLibraries
```

I get this error:

> --useSqlite|-sqlite option is obsolete now. Use --databaseProvider|-dbProvider instead in the future.
>
> To scaffold controllers and views using models, install Entity Framework core packages and try again:   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

Comment: I think the error is clear in its context.

Comment: Regarding your error message it would b great if you could share few more detailsl, first of all, how many nuget package you have installed, In addition, hows your dbContext looks like?